# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS2 respawn

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, respawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS2 community,

I'm currently playing around with the best way to respawn a node (ROS2 foxy). My current solution exists of two files (see below). The first file ("test_package_launch.py") defines the generate_launch_description() method. This file is invoked with "ros2 launch test_package test_package_launch.py".  Within the launch file the ExecuteProcess invokes the second file ("test_package_respawn.py").

So far everything works fine and also it's working as expected. I just don't like the fact to have two files. Is there a way to do this in a single file?

Thanks
Jeremy

**test_package_launch.py:**

```
import sys
import os

from launch import LaunchDescription
import launch
from launch.actions.execute_process import ExecuteProcess
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch import LaunchService
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

def callback_respawn(event, context):
    print("---------------------------------- on exit callback -------------------------------")
    
respawn_delay = 3
def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=[sys.executable, "test_package_respawn.py"],
        respawn=True, respawn_delay=respawn_delay, on_exit=callback_respawn,
        emulate_tty=True,
        output="screen"
        )
    ])
```

**test_package_respawn.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions.execute_process import ExecuteProcess
from launch.actions.shutdown_action import Shutdown
from launch.actions.timer_action import TimerAction
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchService

config = os.path.join(
    get_package_share_directory('test_package'),
    'config',
    'config.yaml'
)

def launch_node():
    return LaunchDescription(
        [Node(
              package="test_package",
              executable="test_package_node",
              name="test_package",
              output="screen",
              emulate_tty=True,
              parameters=[config]
          )
      ]
    )

def main():
  print("------------------------- started node in respawn process -----------------------------")
  desc = launch_node()
  service = LaunchService()
  service.include_launch_description(desc)
  service.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382043/ros2-respawn/) by [**Jeremy**](https://answers.ros.org/users/76193/__jeremy__/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2021-07-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Node actions inherit from ExecuteProcess actions, so you can add the respawn parameters to the Node action. An example:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='orca_base',
            executable='fake_barometer.py',
            output='screen',
            name='fake_barometer',
            respawn=True,
            respawn_delay=4,
        )])
```

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [**Jeremy**](https://answers.ros.org/users/76193/__jeremy__/) on 2021-07-09**:
Thanks that worked.
Just wondering why I didn't work, when I tried this some days ago :-D.

**Comment by [dheeranet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35579/dheeranet/) on 2021-07-11**:
It seems to still not work from XML launch files. Is that known?
There are lots of use cases where XML launch files are "nicer", especially if you want to generate them from something else.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2021-07-14**:
Yes, looks like respawn is missing from the XML parser: https://github.com/ros2/launch/pull/226

It is known: https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/blob/rolling/source/Guides/Launch-files-migration-guide.rst

It certainly would be a nice addition.